# Difference between view_type and view_mode when defining action window?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-view

What exacty does each of these attribute values mean when used while defining act_window, for eg;

```xml
 <record id="open_estimate_quantity_extra_request" model="ir.actions.act_window">
   <field name="name">Extra Requests</field>
   <field name="res_model">estimate.quantity.extra.request</field>
   <field name="view_type">form</field>
   <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
 </record>
```

In the above code what does it mean to have a value of `form` for `view_type` and a value of `tree,form` for `view_mode`.  From what i understand, `view_mode` tells odoo to display both tree and form views for the  `estimate.quantity.extra.request` model.  But what purpose does `view_type` have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, basically view mode shows the sequence and number of the views that shall be available in the view switcher at the top right corner of the tree/form view for a particular model after it is loaded from a menu item or any other way.

if you set view mode to tree,form then first tree view will be shown and then the form view will be opened after you click on one of the records, and the sequence will also be the same as first tree and then form view from left to right in the view switcher at the top right side of the view.

But the view type means how the record will be opened, means if it is set to form then when you click on one of the records in a tree view it will be opened in the form view, if you create a new record an empty form view will be opened,

But if the view type is set to tree then when you click the record it will not be opened in the form view and when you create a new record it will be created as a new row in the tree view

Answer (score 1):

view_mode if defining the list of view mode and the sequence :

```xml
<field name="view_mode">tree,form,graph,...</field>
```

but view type_type there is two (tree or form) when you choose tree you can make a special hierarchic tree best example

[image]

but when you change the type_view from tree to form all  the children records cannot be seen :

[image]

view_type it's used for Hierarchy tree view, see account module to see how is the don you need to compute level field and you need a one2many field children recordSet

see Model `_name = "account.financial.report"`

[EDITS] :
The key to this is in the tree and the action

```xml
<record id="view_account_report_tree_hierarchy" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">account.report.hierarchy</field>
    <field name="model">account.financial.report</field>
    <!-- this field one2many field and the compute field level -->
    <field name="field_parent">children_ids</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <tree string="Account Reports Hierarchy">
            <field name="name"/>
            <field name="type"/>
            <field name="parent_id" invisible="1"/>
            <field name="account_report_id"/>
        </tree>
    </field>
</record>
```